# How to force a particular view in asp.net mvc to go back to http if on an https connections?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ssl

Read carefully. I want to do the following:

If my site is connected via `https://my.domain.com` I want it to go back to `http://my.domain.com/thisview` when I visit a certain view on my site. The reason for this is that some third party scripts (social media feeds) are loading without ssl, and I cannot get them to load over ssl (not supported).

I tried this:

```
routes.Add(new Route("Connect/Index", new MvcRouteHandler())
        {
            Defaults = new RouteValueDictionary(new {controller = "Connect", action = "Index"}),
            DataTokens = new RouteValueDictionary(new { scheme = "http"})
        });
```

Comment: Are social media feeds more important than security? Switching some pages to http means you required unsecure cookies (sending session information in the clear). What social media feeds are you using that doesn't support https?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the EnsureSSL() and EnsureNonSSL() methods in the open source .NET ecommerce framework, NopCommerce. You could even create action filter attributes so that you can just annotate your desired action methods as [EnsureSSL] or [EnsureNonSSL].

Answer (score 0):

`RequireHttpsAttribute` has been baked into the ASP.NET MVC framework for some time now, and it's pretty easy to refactor it into a `FilterAttribute` that does just the opposite ([lifted from this blog post](https://tusksoft.com/blog/posts/9/how-to-force-pages-to-not-use-ssl-in-asp-net-mvc-by-creating-a-forbidhttpsattribute)):

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class ForbidHttpsAttribute : FilterAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{
    public virtual void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("filterContext");
        }

        if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsSecureConnection)
        {
            HandleHttpsRequest(filterContext);
        }
    }

    protected virtual void HandleHttpsRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        // only redirect for GET requests, otherwise the browser might not propagate the verb and request
        // body correctly.

        if (!String.Equals(filterContext.HttpContext.Request.HttpMethod, "GET", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("The requested resource can only be accessed *without* SSL.");
        }

        // redirect to HTTP version of page
        var url = "http://" + filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.Host + filterContext.HttpContext.Request.RawUrl;
        filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult(url);
    }
}
```